# issues with parsing time out of a datetime in c#

Tags: c#, sql

Having an issue with parsing a datetime in C#, I'v looked at the other questions asked on here and the code i use is pretty much identical. The issue is kind of unique. Here is my code

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(BookingDateTime.ToString());
                                dt.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
```

the date it "parses" comes out as 01/08/2021 12:00:00 rather than just pulling the 12:00 part out.
When this code is inserted in my select statement it inserts just the time 12:00:00 and works for 14 iterations of my forloop before breaking due to it not being in the correct format.

```
$"SELECT * FROM [***].[***].[****] WHERE (Id = {Id} AND StartTime = '{dt}'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do **NOT** concatenate strings to build SQL queries, use parameters. You code, in addition to being fragile, is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: they are in parameters, code was changed when posting on here

Comment: If you're using parameters, you just pass a datetime, the format is irrelevant then (datetimes don't even have any format).

Comment: @Alejandro: While I'm not countering the notion that parametrization is allround better, not every concatenated string is inherently an injection attack vector. Given that the concatenated data is distilled from a `DateTime`, there is no way for any malicious commands to filter through in this particular case.

Comment: @Flater Injection is not just an *attack* problem, it's also about *correctness*, and passing through strings and hoping they will parse properly is likely to cause syntax errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dt.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
```

This method does not alter the value of `dt`. It **returns** the string value based on the specified format.

Change your code to:

```
string timestamp = dt.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
```

And you'll find what you're looking for in `timestamp`.

---

> the date it "parses" comes out as 01/08/2021 12:00:00 rather than just pulling the 12:00 part out

You're not asking for `hh:mm` (which is what "12:00" would be), you are asking for `hh:mm:ss tt`, which would return "12:00:00 AM".

Comment: Worked, i was close, just slightly off
thank you for the answer. will accept in when it allows me too